# Antlr4 grammar accepting a number of closing parentheses

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have my Antlr4 grammar file looking like the below,

```
myVal : '(' myVal ')'                                               
     | MINUS myVal                                                 
     | NOT myVal                                                   
     | '$' IDENTIFIER '(' ')'                                     
     | '$' IDENTIFIER '(' myVal (',' myVal)* ')'                    
     | myVal op=(MULT | DIVIDE) myVal                               
     | myVal op=(PLUS | MINUS) myVal                                
     | myVal op=(EQ | NE | GT | GTE | LT | LTE) myVal               
     | myVal IN '[' myVal (',' myVal)* ']'                           
     | myVal '~' myVal                                              
     | myVal op=(AND | OR) myVal                                    
     | myVal '?' myVal ':' myVal                                     
     | IF myVal THEN myVal (ELSEIF myVal THEN myVal)* ELSE myVal       
     | IDENTIFIER DOT IDENTIFIER                                  
     | STRINGLIT                                                  
     | '[' myVal (',' myVal)* ']'                                   
     | TRUE                                                       
     | FALSE                                                      
     | IDENTIFIER                                                 
     | NUMBER                                                     
     | INTEGER                                                    
     ;
```

I am expecting an error for the following condition, but instead, it doesn't give any.

```
(3+4)))
```

The last two parentheses should be errored out.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Always use EOF-terminated rules for a start rule. `inp : myVal EOF;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by Kaby as a comment: make sure you test the input with a rule that has the `EOF` (end of file) at the end.

If you test `myVal` with the input `(3+4)))`, it will gladly parse `(3+4)` and leave the trailing 2 `)`'s in the token stream. After all, the input `(3+4)` *is* successfully parsed my the parser rule `myVal`.

So if you want to make sure *all* tokens are consumed, you need to tell the parser it has to consume all tokens until the `EOF` is encountered:

```
testMyVal
 : myVal EOF
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Do I have to update my Lexer or parser for this?

Comment: You add `testMyVal` to your parser.